# PowerShell: How to select multiple names in Where-object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to list some of software installed on a PC by using:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |
Select-Object -Property name,version |
Where-Object {$_.name -like '*Java*'}
```

It works, but when I added more names in `Where-Object` it gave me no results neither an error.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |
Select-Object -Property name,version |
Where-Object {$_.name -like '*Java*','*python*','*adobe*','*access*'}
```

Why does it only work with one name?

Comment: BTW, how about listing all 64 bit software? I dont think there is a 'Win64_Product' command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `-like` will take an array on the right hand side.  Try a regex instead:

```
Where-Object {$_.name -match 'Java|python|adobe|access'}
```

Comment: yes, looks like -like wont take array...Thanks, will accept answer after 7 mins

Comment: BTW, how about listing all 64 bit software? I dont think there is a 'Win64_Product' command

Answer (score 1):

The -Like operator takes a string argument (not a string array), so whatever you give it will get cast as [string]. If you cast the arguments you've give it to string:

```
[string]('*Java*','*python*','*adobe*','*access*')
```

you get:

```
*Java* *python* *adobe* *access*
```

and that's what you're trying to match against (and you don't have any file names that look like that).

The easiest way to do this is switch to the -match operator, and an alternating regex:

```
Where-Object { $_.name -match 'Java|python|adobe|access' }
```